# DifferentialRoot with no explicit branch cuts

Tags: differential-equations

I have a partial differential equation to solve. However, Mathematica shows solution that is not exactly the way I want.

```
DSolve[{(1 + (I E^(-I km))/(1 + E^(-I km) + E^(I kn)) - E1) ga[km, 
  kn] + ((I E^(-I km))/(1 + E^(-I km) + E^(I kn)) + 
   I (1 + E^(I km) + E^(-I kn)) (1 + E^(-I km) + E^(I kn)) - 
   E1^2) Derivative[1, 0][ga][km, kn] + 
Derivative[2, 0][ga][km, kn] == 0}, ga[km, kn], km]
```

Is there a way to extract out some meaningful solutions from the above equation?

This equation comes from the two coupled equations

```
E1 ga[km, kn] -I Derivative[1, 0][ga][km, kn] = (1+E^(I kn)+ E^(-I km))gb[km, kn]        
E1 gb[km, kn] -I Derivative[1, 0][gb][km, kn] = (1+E^(-I kn)+ E^(I km))ga[km, kn]
```

Then one writes a single equation for `ga[km, kn]` that gives the original equation on the top.

Comment: I do not see an ode or a pde in there. Better show the Input form. May be cut/paste issue. May be you can post the Latex or a screen shot from the book to make it more clear. I get syntax error when pasting what you posted.

Comment: @Shamina, I assume that by ``ga^(2,0)`` you mean $\partial^2ga(k_m, k_n)/\partial k_m^2$. However, this is not the correct notation in Wolfram Language. Please take a look at [`D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) and [`Derivative`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html), or the examples in [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) to see how you should write the derivatives. Oh, it also might be that you just copied the Plain Text instead of the input form.

Comment: @Nasser it is a cut/paste issue. I have also put the latex version also. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: @Domen You are right! This is what I meant and again it maybe the cut/paste issue, as I said before. However, I have now put the latex version.

Comment: You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! I will.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my parochial interpretation.  I welcome others more fluent in the matter to improve the code and explanation.

The DifferentialRoot is a solution to a differential equation.  Setting E1=1, You PDE is:

```
 E1=1;   
 dr = DSolve[{(1 + (I E^(-I km))/(1 + E^(-I km) + E^(I kn)) - E1) ga[
           km, kn] + ((I E^(-I km))/(1 + E^(-I km) + E^(I kn)) + 
            I (1 + E^(I km) + E^(-I kn)) (1 + E^(-I km) + E^(I kn)) - 
            E1^2) Derivative[1, 0][ga][km, kn] + 
         Derivative[2, 0][ga][km, kn] == 0}, ga[km, kn], km]
```

with:

$$ \text{dr}=c_2 S_2[e^{i km};kn]+c_1 S_1[e^{i km};kn]
$$

$S_1(x;kn)$ and $S_2(x;kn)$ are solutions to the associated (ordinary)  DifferentialRoot IVP in terms of $y(x)$ with parameter $kn$  and initial conditions $y[1]=1$ and $y'[1]=0$.  You can see the DEs by clicking on the DifferentialRoot icons of dr.

For now set $c_1=1$ and $c_2=0$ and just work with one DifferentialRoot:

```
f = ga[km, kn] /. (dr[[1, 1]] /. {C[2] -> 0, C[1] -> 1})
```

Now check a value of the solution:

```
f /. {km -> 1.2, kn -> 2.3}


(* 0.472088 - 0.0084236 I*)
```

Now plot an example plot for $-1\leq km\leq 1$ and $-1\leq kn\leq 1$:

```
Plot3D[Re[f /. {km -> p, kn -> q}], {p, -1, 1}, {q, -1, 1}]
```

[image]